# Glassfish JPA: Problems injecting EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, entitymanager

I am new to Java EE. I tried to get some first examples running (JPA). 
I am using Glassfish v3. The trouble is that I don't get the App Server injecting 
the EntityManager. Hear is one example http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_persistence_jpa_for
  which I extended with a JSP client.

Entity:

```
package beans;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

BookService Interface:

```
package beans;
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface BookService {
    Book createOrUpdate(Book book);
    void remove(Book book);
    Book find(Object id);
}
```

BookServiceBean:

```
package beans;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class BookServiceBean implements BookService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Book createOrUpdate(Book book) {
        return em.merge(book);
    }
    public void remove(Book book) {
        em.remove(em.merge(book));
    }
    public Book find(Object id) {
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/MarcelsDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="beans.BookServiceBean" %>
<%@ page import="beans.Book" %>
<html>
<body>
<%
    BookServiceBean bs = new BookServiceBean();
    Book b = new Book("Superman");
    bs.createOrUpdate(b);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run the example I get a java.lang.NullPointerException in the createOrUpdate() method so the entityManager is 
obviously not injected correctly. I tried to find a remedy for days now and
some help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Marcel

Comment: Isn't there also a problem with the fact he's using state in a @Stateless EJB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because you are instantiating your `BookService` with a `new()` - which is basically wrong - and nothing gets injected in the EJB. EJB are component that are managed by the container and should be obtained either via injection or with a lookup.

Here, while the JSP spec allows any code to be run in a scriplet, calling an EJB from a JSP is actually not really encouraged and JSPs don't support injection. In other words, you'll have to use a lookup:

```
<%@ page import="beans.BookService" %>
<%@ page import="beans.Book" %>
<html>
<body>
<%
    BookService bs = (BookService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/BookServiceBean")
    Book b = new Book("Superman");
    bs.createOrUpdate(b);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

But you should call your EJB from a Servlet or a JSF Managed Bean (and your EJB could be injected in such components).

If you need some samples, have a look at the [Java EE Code Samples & Apps](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/).

**Update:** See [How do I access a Local EJB component from a POJO?](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#POJOLocalEJB) in the EJB FAQ for more details on JNDI (especially the new [portable global JNDI names defined by the EJB 3.1 specification](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_)).

Comment: Thank you very much. Very good explanation. I get:
    
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: BookServiceBean not found
???

Comment: @Marcel I was not totally sure about the JNDI name under which the bean would be available. Look at the GlassFish console, the JDNI name should be logged in there.

Comment: It worked like this:
InitialContext().lookup("java:module/BookServiceBean");
Thank you again.
Greets

Comment: Pascal, Thanks for this one too, I was having the same issue. I did not realize I could not create a new bean, I appreciate it. I used netbeans code generation to access mine, I am still not up to speed with the naming conventions that I can get that lookup name right without a little help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "sample")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: That won't help as long as he is using the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I changed this already and it doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating the service bean directly, when you really need to be having the container inject it (via @EJB).  This isn't supported in a JSP, though, so you'll have to switch to a servlet as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I use @EJB in a servlet I get a compilation error: The annotation @EJB is disallowed for this location. MMMMMMMMM

Marcel

Comment: Could you mabye post a little example. sorry i am a novice

Comment: Ok. It has to be outside of the methods now I get a very nice Exception:

Comment: Exception:
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/controllers.BookController/bs' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.BookController/bs,Remote 3.x interface =beans.BookServiceBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=beans.BookServiceBean,refType=Session' .

Comment: Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'beans.BookServiceBean#beans.BookServiceBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'beans.BookServiceBean#beans.BookServiceBean' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: beans.BookServiceBean#beans.BookServiceBean not found]]]